# Eclipse IIntroPart throwing exception when trying to load ActionBars

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a class implementing IIntroPart and inside the creation method-

public void createPartControl(Composite container) {

```
    Browser browser = new Browser(container,SWT.NONE);
    browser.setUrl(STRHTMLPATH+File.separator+"wc.html");

    IActionBars bars = getIntroSite().getActionBars(); //NULL POINTER
```

First two lines are working perfectly alright and its loading the browser as well, but when I am trying to load the actionBars as I do in View, I am getting NullPointerException here.
What is the issue.

> Unable to create view ID org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview: An
>   unexpected exception was thrown.

Above is the message thrown before the Exception Stack

Comment: getIntroSite() implementation code?

Comment: yes there I passed Null , can you tell me what should be the exact input for the same.

Comment: Extended the IntroPart class and sort it out, thanks for the input